# Reset/Remove ErrorDocument via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-400, errordocument

I use host that has custom ErrorDocument settings already set in their httpd.conf and I can't edit this file (I don't have access) to solve the problem directly there.

***Some background:*** I use an API that when something isn't right I manually set a responde code and print a json as error response to use in client side. Since I am triggering a response code (**400 - Bad Request** in my case) it falls directly in the **catch** of my Ajax request.

Their configuration for a custom 400 error page is causing this issue, the response of my API never returns because i got as response their custom page.

---

Is it possible to remove/reset or set it to show the page that triggered the *error* of an already set ErrorDocument via .htaccess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On server where virtual server settings cannot be modified but .htaccess is accessible, this works for me:

```
ErrorDocument 401 default
ErrorDocument 402 default
ErrorDocument 403 default
ErrorDocument 404 default
ErrorDocument 500 default
ErrorDocument 501 default
ErrorDocument 502 default
ErrorDocument 503 default
ErrorDocument 504 default
```

Put it into .htaccess and it will reset error handling pages.

Comment: will this show the output of a php script that errored ?